# How did they fill the bags with paper in Ocean's Eleven?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-eleven

It is shown that the bags of money are in fact bags full of some paper. How did the Oceans gang manage to achieve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0240772/trivia?tab=gf#plot_hole)

> The DVD commentary admits that there was no way in which all the flyers that were carried out of the casino and driven to the airport could have been in the vault.