# How do they agree to believe the necklace might have slipped off Daphne's neck?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-8

In the movie Oceans Eight - in the scene when Weil tries on the necklace on Daphne they find out that the necklace can be opened only by the special magnet carried by Cartier's bodyguards.

However, during the actual heist, when Tammy finds the duplicate necklace and gives it to Daphne, they all agree that the necklace might have accidentally dropped into the water.

Even the Cartier guys seem to agree. Whereas, Cartier very well knows that the necklace cannot be opened without the special magnetic device.

So, how is it that Cartier casually agree or believe that the necklace might have slipped off ?

Answer (score 4):

My best guesses are that

- The two guards from Cartier are scared for their jobs and/or any other repercussions that could come from losing the necklace (i.e., Cartier thinking they stole it) that they don't really care what happened to the necklace, only that it has returned.
- Even though the necklace can only be opened with a special magnet, that doesn't preclude the possibility that Daphne's head is small enough for the necklace to have slipped off, especially because ostensibly she went into the restroom to vomit and so she could have conceivably been in a position for her head to be upside down and for it to slip off.
- It could have been understood that the special magnet was not designed to make sure it stays secured to the neck of the wearer but rather to make it difficult for a thief to remove by unlatching it. The movie's purpose in showing us the magnet ahead of time is both to explain that they needed to modify their plans around this development as well as give some reason why Daphne clued in that something was going on when Rose reacted the way she did.

But ultimately this is the movie series that gave us the hooker fliers [plot hole](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/717/how-did-they-fill-the-bags-with-paper-in-oceans-eleven), so this necklace thing might not be completely bulletproof as well

Answer (score 2):

Given the fact that the necklace was **found** in the water, the most plausible explanation would be that it fell off her neck. After all, she was running and clutching her stomach, and would have reasonably been leaning over due to her nausea and stomach pains. The guards would have agreed because, as Tom Kidd mentioned in his answer, they *needed* a plausible explanation because they were probably scared for their jobs.